# Running into a Jest/enzyme error "Popper: Invalid reference or popper argument provided."

Tags: jestjs, popperjs

I wrote a tooltip using popperjs 2.2.1, and jest/enzyme tests. However, I get the following error:

`Error: Cannot read property 'split' of undefined`

`console.error ../../node_modules/@popperjs/core/dist/cjs/popper.js:630`

`Popper: Invalid reference or popper argument provided. They must be either a DOM element or virtual element.`

Tried all of the recommendations in (maybe did it wrong as I am just getting into jest): 
https://github.com/popperjs/popper-core/issues/478 and https://github.com/popperjs/react-popper/issues/263

I recreated it in the codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/tooltip-test-r8nqt?file=/src/Tooltip.spec.tsx

Any advice? tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not providing a `placement` property in the `defaultProps` object of your tests.